# Dynamic Namespace with XQuery inside SQL Server

Tags: xquery-sql

I have a link for my namespace that changes depending on other data. It looks similar to this.

```
@xml = myXML
@id = myID

@xml.nodes('declare namespace myS="myLink.com/@id";/myS:foo')
```

Since namespace does not allow variables inside the link because of this error

"Syntax error near 'declare namespace', expected string literal."

Is there anyway to dynamically change the namespace url without hard coding any values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because `.nodes()` expects a string literal and namespaces must be string literals, there is no way to make the namespace dynamic short of constructing the whole statement using dynamic SQL. However, you can select nodes without referring to an explicit namespace declaration. This will select any element named "foo" regardless of namespace:

```
@xml.nodes('/*[local-name()="foo"]')
```

If you really need to select an element with a particular dynamic namespace, you can use `namespace-uri()`:

```
DECLARE @myNS NVARCHAR(MAX) = REPLACE('myLink.com/$id', '$id', @id);
@xml.nodes('/*[local-name()="foo" and namespace-uri()=sql:variable("@myNS")]')
```

Aside from being clumsy, this may have performance issues -- XPath really likes it if you keep namespaces constant. If possible, change your input so the set of namespaces is well-defined.